# Prestashop changes to theme

Tags: css, themes, prestashop

I have been tasked with making a small design change (CSS) to a Prestashop site that used an off the shelf theme.

I know that in WordPress you can make a child theme to put your design changes in which is best practice.

Is there a similar method I should be using in Prestashop?  Or alternatively is there anywhere in the dashboard I can put these changes?

Comment: Do you want to change FO or BO theme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building from a default theme, then the correct way would be to go to `Themes > Add New Theme > Create New Theme > Copy default-bootstrap` and create a new theme.

There are no child themes in PrestaShop (any kind of inheritance system for themes would majorly complicate an already complex system). What you have is what you work with. If you bought a third party theme, then go modify it directly (modify `.tpl` files, modify `global.css`, etc.). IF you copied default theme, then work with your copy (just don't work with default theme, it may get updated).

An event better way would be to install `compass` and modify `.sass` files (that is the most **correctest** :D way).